# sql statement to check the length of an attribute value in sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Is there a way to write a query that returns the results according to the length of a specific attribute value in sqlite3 ?

For instance I have table X as :

id statements

1  "new-york library"

2  "hudson river"

...

how could we write an sql query for the question: " Get me the statements that have character-length less than 13".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select statements 
from X
where length (statements) < 13
```